# I had this error while installing cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, xcode10

error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

Comment: Might just be a network problem. Does it happen consistently?

Comment: yes i guess my network is slow.@ThomasW

Comment: So you don't have the problem anymore?